# jQuery find not working with object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This code doesn't work

```
var next = $("#orders").find(".next");
            if (next.length == 1) {
                var address = $(next[0]).find(".directionsAddress");
                var destination = $(address[0]).text();
            }

<div id="orders" class="ui-sortable">
  <div id="companyAddress" class="noDisplay">101 Billerica Avenue, North Billerica, MA</div>
  <div id="companyPhone" class="noDisplay">9788353181</div><div class="next"></div>
  <div class="lat">42.616007</div>
  <div class="lng">-71.31187</div>
  <div id="section1611" class="sectionMargin borderRad">
    <div class="directionsAddress noDisplay">92+Swan+Street+Lowell+MA</div>
```

It is suppose to find one div with a class of "next" that I know exists on the page, then within that one item of the result set array, there will be one div with a class name of directionsAddress.

The "next" array is coming back with a length of 1, so it looks like the problem is with my $(next[0]).find because the address array is coming back as 0 length and I am making a syntax error of some sort that I don't understand.

Comment: If there is only one `div` with class `next`, then why find the `div` with class `directionsAddress` within the set of `div`s with class `next` if you know that there's only one `div` with class `next` to begin with, since the `div` with class `next` must be the `div` with `directionsAddress`?

Comment: @fuyushimoya, both are the same

Comment: Yep, see that, deleted my prev comment.

Comment: Show us your html code

Comment: <div id="orders" class="ui-sortable"><div id="companyAddress" class="noDisplay">101 Billerica Avenue, North Billerica, MA</div><div id="companyPhone" class="noDisplay">9788353181</div><div class="next"></div><div class="lat">42.616007</div><div class="lng">-71.31187</div><div id="section1611" class="sectionMargin borderRad"><div class="directionsAddress noDisplay">92+Swan+Street+Lowell+MA</div>

Comment: The reason why I have to find a div with a class of "next" is because sometimes it might not be there. And if it is there, my UI only allows for one instance of it, so it's either 0 or 1. And if there is a div found, that's the div instance that I want to get the value of directionsAddress from. Directions address is repeated in many items that are not of class "next".

Comment: @user192632 is better to update the question with the html than include the code in a comment, Anyway you are not finding `.directionsAdress` because `.directionAddress` is not inside `.next`

Comment: I just think I'm misunderstanding the syntax and that I can't call $(next[0]).find() because it's not valid.

Comment: What if you use `.closest()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: The div tag with the class of next is not closed in the code I posted, but the div with .directionsAddress is opened and closed before the close of the div with next class. So it should be inside that div that has a class of next

Comment: @user192632. it isn't. This is what you got: `<div class="next"></div>`. There's nothing inside.

Comment: in the html you posted it isn't

Comment: reposted the html in original question so it's easier to read. I;m not posting all of the html, but the div with the class of next isn't closed in the code I posted, but the div with directionsAddress is

Comment: You don't need to use `$(next[0]).find()`, just use `next.find()`.

Comment: Ah, just saw what wallek is talking about. I'm not supposed to close the next div but I did. I don't know how stuff works here but if anybody wants to post this as an answer I can voter on it

Comment: And `$(address[0]).text()` should just be `address.text()`. Why do you think you need to convert the jQuery object to a DOM object and then back to jQuery?

Comment: I'll try next.find as that seems a little more elegant

Comment: Great answers guys. I really appreciate the help as I'm pretty new at this

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  You need to find the parent (or alternatively, the sibling of `.next`) then try to find the applicable `.directionsAddress`.

```
var next = $("#orders").find(".next");
if (next.length == 1) {
    var destination = $(next).parent().find(".directionsAddress");
    alert($(destination).text());
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00fgpv6L/

Comment: That's a good solution and it will work. But it seems that my problem was closing the div with the class of next right away. It is suppose to close much further down in the html. So now .directionsAddress does fall inside of the div with the class of next

Comment: I'd look into jQuery data() and data attr, you can flag the #orders div with the fact it has an address instead of doing a check on .next.